# Do search engine spiders find included content

Tags: php, seo

IF I have a webpage that uses php and I include another page like so:

```
<?php include_once "folder/pageWithText.php"; ?>
```

Will the text on the included page be found by the spider?

Comment: It will get all data that is echoed by PHP into the html.

Comment: But it will not see the file name of the included file, if you want to know that.

Comment: What do you think? Does the spider(client) see those php tags in your page source or the actual content?

Comment: obviously the search engine sees what your code OUTPUTS, not your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. The browser finds it, so a search engine bot will. They work the same way (except that a browser is more likely to execute client side JavaScript, which PHP isn't).